# Solving the given IVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $a,b$ be constants with $a>0.$ Consider the IVP
$$u_t=a \Delta u+b |\nabla u|^2=0~~in~~R^n \times (0,\infty), u=g~~on~~R^n \times \{ t=0 \}$$
using the transformation $w=\phi(u)$ with proper choice of $\phi,$ and then $(ii)$ use the solution formula for $w.$

Can someone explain me how to use the solution formula to solve this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is the [Hopf-Cole transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation#Heat_equation). See [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/am_/npd.pdf) for a detailed outline of the procedure in one dimension.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I still couldn't get it done. I'll keep on working on it.

Comment: Suppose $\phi$ is just some arbitrary smooth function for the moment, and set $w=\phi(u)$. What PDE does $w$ satisfy?

Comment: @Jeff $w_t=\phi_u  u_t =\phi_u ( a \Delta u+b |\nabla u|^2 )=0.$

Comment: @ManMath You're not differentiating $w$ correctly. You should get $w_t = \phi'(u)u_t$, $w_{x_i} =\phi'(u)u_{x_i}$ and $w_{x_ix_i} = \phi''(u)u_{x_i}^2 + \phi'(u)u_{x_ix_i}$.

Comment: @Jeff is it $w_{x_i}=-1$ or gradient ?

Comment: @ManMath Start with $w_t=\phi'(u)u_t$, and substitute for $u_t$ using the IVP. It would help if you show us the work you have so far (you can edit the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set $$u = \psi(w) \quad (1)$$ we can differentiate $u$, substitute the result into our PDE and in turn construct a $\psi = \phi^{-1}$ that returns the linear heat equation (assuming a few conditions and that the inverse function even exists; see the link I put in the comments). Differentiating gives

\begin{align}
u_{t} &= \psi_{w} w_{t} \\
\nabla u &= \psi_{w} \nabla w \\
\Delta u &= \nabla (\nabla u) \\
&= \nabla (\psi_{w} \nabla w) \\
&= \nabla(\psi_{w}) \nabla w + \psi_{w} \nabla (\nabla w) \\
&= \psi_{ww} \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} + \psi_{w} \Delta w
\end{align}

and so our PDE becomes

\begin{align}
\psi_{w} \nabla w &= a(\psi_{ww} \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} + \psi_{w} \Delta w) + b \lvert \psi_{w} \nabla w \rvert^{2} \\
&= \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2}(a \psi_{ww} + b \psi_{w}^{2}) + a \psi_{w} \Delta w
\end{align}

In order to obtain the linear heat equation, we require

$$a \psi_{ww} + b \psi_{w}^{2} = 0$$

which is a nonlinear second order ODE. This can be solved by setting $z = \psi_{w}$, separating and integrating (setting the integration constant to be zero for convenience) which gives

$$\psi = \frac{b}{a} \ln \left ( \frac{a}{b} w \right )$$

Hence,

$$u = \frac{b}{a} \ln \left ( \frac{a}{b} w \right ) \implies w = \frac{b}{a} \exp \left ( \frac{a}{b} u \right ) = \phi(u)$$

which satisfies

$$w_{t} = a \Delta w$$

Comment: @ Mattos thank you. I'll go through this.